# How to create a table with both static and dynamic values from parameters?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create a table with static and dynamic values like the following picture:

[image: example]

As you can see, the red values are dynamic (values in parameters) while the rest of the table is static.

The problem is that I cannot add more than one detail row to the table.

Even if I use normal Text Field and Static Text elements instead of a Table I wouldn't be able to stretch the values (in case a value needs more than a single line) without overlapping.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the `datasource` for this? A Jasper `Table` is not the appropriate structure unless your DataSource is a list of `PersonalInformationItems` that contain a `name` and `value`, which make the whole table dynamic.  If you're datasource is a `List<PersonalInfo>` then you probably just want a List with the content being 4 rows of text fields.

Comment: I'm trying to pass 4 parameters like in the pictures. I know I can do that using Static Text with some formatting. But the issue is when the text is lengthy that it takes more than one line then I wouldn't be able to stretch those texts without being crossed and overlapped. Your solution is OK and I'm using it right now but it's more a workaround rather a real solid solution. Even though I have been searching for a solution for more than two days it seems that Jasper Reports doesn't have a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `jr:table` component you need to have a datasource, **normally** you should get the data from some backend code, passing it to the report for example as a `List` in a parameter. Hence instead of passing the single parameters, you pass a datasource with both name and values.

However, *for fun?* we can create a datasource also within the jrxml code for example in your case I would use a [`ListOfArrayDataSource(java.util.List<java.lang.Object[]> records, java.lang.String[] columnNames)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/ListOfArrayDataSource.html#ListOfArrayDataSource-java.util.List-java.lang.String:A-)

The code to create the first two entries would be something this.

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.ListOfArrayDataSource(
   Arrays.asList(
      new String[]{"Name", $P{name}}, 
      new String[]{"Date of Birth", $P{dateOfBirth}}
      ),
   new String[]{"c1", "c2"}
)
```

**Full jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_15" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="342c93fd-9f0b-49db-a6e8-dbc252bbeca4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset" uuid="604ce812-0b69-47fa-862f-c6b4356c6b62">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="c1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="c2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Nasser Ali"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="dateOfBirth" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1985-10-07"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="400" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000000" uuid="56949b5f-9b21-4f88-9660-ddccce0e7cad"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Personal information]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="400" height="30" uuid="7a9309f0-4b5f-4c01-9b0a-611807b01f96">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset" uuid="f682c987-479a-40f9-8b97-bf07577e67fa">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.ListOfArrayDataSource(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Name", $P{name}}, new String[]{"Date of Birth", $P{dateOfBirth}}),new String[]{"c1", "c2"})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="c087b83b-e6f9-4366-b655-eb7c14e35745">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="dce0c9d6-ec99-4cbb-b981-73d3dff1b67b"/>
                                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="dad64648-00cb-46ff-9f74-216170605bf6">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" forecolor="#FF0400" uuid="05d673a9-93d4-4b3e-a4eb-6fd5fd171b30"/>
                                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output:**

[image: Result]